# Possible improvements for RewriteRules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So, I just managed to write some `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` for a custom site that I developed a while ago and as I'm a beginner in all of this, I was hopping that somebody will review my code and tell me if there's anything to improve or if it is good as it is.

What I'm trying to achieve is to convert from `/?mod=x` to `/x` and from `/?mod=x&type=y-z` to `/x/y-z`

And here's what I've done by now:

```
# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([a-z]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?mod=$1&tipo=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([a-z]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?mod=$1 [NC,L]
```

So, everything ok? Or, is there room for improvement?

Comment: This looks fine to me. Have you considered trailing slashes? e.g.`/x/y-z/` and `/x/`

Comment: @ImCR, I already do that... just didn't mentioned it in the code, check the update (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine these lines and remove the `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([a-z]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?mod=$1&tipo=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([a-z]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?mod=$1 [NC,L]
```

To:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ /?mod=$1&tipo=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /?mod=$1 [NC,L]
```

Otherwise, this looks fine.

---

> I'm trying to add one last improvement (regarding htaccess), and that is that I would like it to redirect /?mod=inicio to /inicio. So I'm trying to do it with the following code, but It keeps building the url like this /inicio?mod=inicio

This rule directly conflicts with your other rules. They will rewrite each other because the target of one rule is the regex match of the other. Also, you need a `?` at the end of your target to remove the actual query string. You need to match against the actual request:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?mod=([a-z]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L]
```

Comment: thank you, that is indeed very useful (less code = better), but please do check my question's update, hope you can help

Comment: @w0rldart Not really related to the original question but I edited the answer

Comment: I created a new question with an extra detail, over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485120/redirecting-query-string-to-friendly-url sorry for my mistake