# Redirecting %{QUERY_STRING} to friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to add one last improvement (regarding htaccess), and that is that I would like it to redirect `/?mod=inicio` to `/inicio`. So I'm trying to do it with the following code, but It keeps building the url like this `/inicio?mod=inicio`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mod=([a-z]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /%1 [L]
```

Same thing with extra parameters: from `/?mod=x&type=y-z` to `/x/y-z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?mod=([a-z]+)&type=([a-z\-]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?mod=([a-z]+)($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L]
```

The key is to match against the actual request instead of the URI because your other rules (from your previous question) will cause these rewrites to match, they'll conflict with each other. The other key point is to include a `?` at the end of the targets (e.g. `/%1/%2?`) which makes it so the query string *doesn't get appended*.

Comment: thank you very much Sir, for your answer and sharing some of your knowledge.